# ORA-00904: "SQUARE": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider `P(a, c)` and `Q(b, d)` to be two points on a 2D plane where `(a,b)` are the **respective minimum and maximum values of Northern Latitude** (LAT_N) and `(c,d)` are the **respective minimum and maximum values of Western Longitude** (LONG_W) in `STATION`. Query the Euclidean Distance between points P and Q and format your answer to display 4 decimal digits.

```
STATION(ID, CITY, STATE, LAT_N, LONG_W)
```

MY QUERY -

```
SELECT ROUND(SQRT(SQUARE(MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N)) + SQUARE(MIN(LONG_W) - MAX(LONG_W))), 4) FROM STATION;
```

I GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR :

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "SQUARE": invalid identifier
```

WHAT IS THE WAY OUT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `power()`:

```
SELECT ROUND(SQRT(POWER(MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N), 2) + 
                  POWER(MIN(LONG_W) - MAX(LONG_W), 2)
                 ), 4)
FROM STATION;
```

Comment: YEAH I TRIED THIS RIGHT NOW, THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a self-product? If so, instead of:

```
SQRT(SQUARE(MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N))
```

Just use:

```
SQRT((MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N)) * (MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N)))
```

Or you can use `POWER()`:

```
SQRT(POWER(MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N), 2)
```